# jQuery: Look up table value

Tags: jquery, html-table, lookup

I'm trying to create to use a table as a look-up table.  Normally, I would do this server side, but in this case I just have an html table and the table is going to be inputted by the client.

Basically, when filling out a form they give me two values which are in columns A & B. Then the form needs to do a calculation using the corresponding value in Column C. Column A is repeated multiple times, rather then entering it multiple times, the rowspan attribute is used, which seems to be really complicating this, but it would be a big deal to change (it might be possible, but I'd rather avoid).

A simplified version:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Column A</th><th>Column B</th><th>Column C</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">val1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">val2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So if they input:
    val1 and 1  -> 2
    val2 and 4  -> 5
    val2 and 10 -> 15

The one idea I have is to first parse the table into a nested array and then use it. It appears to work, but I wanted to get others opinion on the best way to handle this. If I could just query/filter based on the DOM it seems like it would use less memory, but again the rowspan attribute seems to make those solutions ugly.

Edit: correct having the second rowspan attribute on the tr tag instead of the td tags
Edit: tried clarifying via the example section that you could potentially look up any row

Comment: so you only need the first row of values under each "val1" and "val2" section? (eg: val1 uses only "2" if val1 and 1 exist? and val2 uses only the number 5 to do its calculations if val2 and 4 exist?) also is there a typo on the second rowspan? (should be in the td tag, correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way (other than working w/ the form data server side) would be to use jQuery to work with the form data directly *before* it's submitted rather than working with the HTML result.

But if you have no control over that, this will bring the first row for each "val#" rowspan's "C" column value into an object keyed by each "val#" string where you can work with it (via a for in loop for example). You should add an "id" attribute (eg: id="myTable") to your table tag because that will optimize the jQuery selector.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  var vals = {}, $table = $('#myTable');

  $table.find('td[rowspan]').each(function(i,e) {
    $(e).siblings().each(function(j,s) {
      var html = e.innerHTML, key = (html.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/)) ? html : i.toString();

      vals[key] = parseInt($(s).html(), 10);
    });
  });

  for(var val in vals) {
    if(!vals[val]) continue;

    vals[val] = vals[val] + 20;

    alert(vals[val]); // alerts 22, then 25
  }
});
```